# Angular 2. Implementing editable primeng data table. Edit column with dropdown and switch

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using primeNG data table in my angular 2 project. It's good, it makes my coding easier but I'm having an issue with implementing editable of primeng data table. It works really well in editing text but not working in editing column with dropdowns and input switch. I forked a plunkr isimilar to my problem.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="persons" [editable]="true"  resizableColumns="true" reorderableColumns="true" tableStyleClass="tablePrimeNgClass"> 
  <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name" [editable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="lastName" [editable]="true" header="Last Name"></p-column>
  <p-column field="favoriteColor" [editable]="true"  header="Favorite Color">
     <template let-col let-color="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="color[col.field]" [options]="favoriteColors" [autoWidth]="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" required="true"></p-dropdown>
    <template>
</p-column>
<p-column field="registered" [editable]="true" header="Registered">
    <template>
       <p-inputSwitch onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" [(ngModel)]="registered"></p-inputSwitch>
     </template>
</p-column></p-dataTable>
```

in my ts

```
eexport class AppComponent {
favoriteColors: SelectItem[] = [
   {label:'red', value:'red'},
   {label:'yellow', value:'yellow'},
   {label:'blue', value:'blue'},
   {label:'black', value:'black'},
   {label:'orange', value:'orange'}
   ];

persons: any [] = [
    {"firstName": "paolo","lastName":"revira","registered":false,"favoriteColor": "red"},
    {"firstName": "kenneth","lastName":"santos","registered":true,"favoriteColor": "blue"},
    {"firstName": "chris","lastName":"kenndy","registered":true,"favoriteColor": "black"},
    {"firstName": "bea","lastName":"stewart","registered":false,"favoriteColor": "pink"},
    {"firstName": "khate","lastName":"wislet","registered":false,"favoriteColor": "yellow"},
  ];

ngOnInit() {

}}
```

How can I implemnt dropdowns and switch in an editable primeng datatable?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `p-dropdown` during editing, your corresponding object should be a object of type `SelectedItem`

```
<p-column field="favoriteColor.value" [editable]="true"  header="Favorite Color">
           <ng-template let-col let-color="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
              <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="color.favoriteColor" [options]="favoriteColors"></p-dropdown>
            </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbxO1leMvGCgeuJjpjFJ?p=preview)**